# Separating documents into different folders in Python

Tags: python, xml, split, directory, document

I have a folder Data with list of documents:

```
A.txt
A.xml
B.txt
B.xml
C.txt
C.xml
...
...
Z.txt
Z.xml
```

How can I split these documemts into three folders: random 50% of them in Folder1,  25% in Folder2, and the rest 25% in Folder3? One document can be only in one folder, and its importsant that documents, for example, M.txt and M.xml were in same folder, not in different ones?

Should it be smth like

```
import random
import io

with io.open("C:/Data", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')

random.shuffle(data)

data1 = data[:50]
data2 = data[50:]
data3=data1[:25]
```

?

but here it says

> Permission denied: 'C:/Data '

And how to write to folders?

Comment: *"Should it be smth [sic] like"* - why don't you **try it and find out?**

Comment: because i don't know how to separate it in folders, i've just found this example but i don't understand does it works according to the logic i need.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe can you help?

Comment: Replace "C:/Data" with the path to your directory. (And backup your directory before doing anything...)

Comment: You know the logic you need, so why are you asking us? Test it!

Comment: but C:/Data is the path to my directory

Comment: @jonrsharpe i know the logic but i don't know how to code this logic, that 's why im asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond a way how to do it, so if smb else will get the same problem, here you are:

```
import os
data=os.listdir("C:\Data")

data1 = data[:50]
data2 = data[50:]
data3=data2[25:]

import shutil
for i in data1:
    shutil.move('C:\Data'+'\\'+i, 'C:\Data\Folder1')
for j in data2:
    shutil.move('C:\Data'+'\\'+j, 'C:\Data\Folder2')
for k in data3:
    shutil.move('C:\Data'+'\\'+k, 'C:\Data\Folder3')
```

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` to join paths rather than concatening path strings. It is safer and multiplatform.